# Make UITextView inside UITableViewCell appear and be editable when didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created a custom table view cell, and I'd like a hidden text view inside it to become visible and to be edited when the user selects that row. Here's how I've attempted that (this cell only appears in the last row of a section)

**table view delegate**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewVar didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ...

    if (indexPath.row == (int)[self.selectedLabels count] - 1 ) {
        [self.lastCell addCustomInfo];
    }

}
```

**table view data source**

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewVar cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        ...

        UITableViewCell *cell;
        if (indexPath.row != [self.labels count] - 1) {
            ...
        } else {
            cell = [self produceTableCellWithNibName:@"SignUpSurveyInputRowTableViewCell" inTableView:tableView withCellIdentifier:@"SignUpSurveyTableViewCell"];
            self.lastCell = cell;
        }

        ...

        return useCell;
    }

- (UITableViewCell *) produceTableCellWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName inTableView:(UITableView *)tableViewVar {
    return [self produceTableCellWithNibName:nibName inTableView:tableViewVar withCellIdentifier:nibName];
}


- (UITableViewCell *) produceTableCellWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName inTableView:(UITableView *)tableViewVar withCellIdentifier:(NSString*) cellId {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableViewVar dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    if( cell == nil ) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                cell = currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

**table view cell methods**

```
- (void) addCustomInfo {

        NSLog(@"inside add custom info");
        self.surveyTextView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        self.surveyTextView.hidden = NO;
        self.surveyTextLabel.hidden = YES;            
        [self setNeedsDisplay];

        [self.surveyTextView becomeFirstResponder];
    }

    - (BOOL)textViewShouldReturn:(UITextView *)textViewVar {
        [textViewVar resignFirstResponder];
        return YES;
    }

    - (void) textViewDidChange:(UITextView *) textViewVar
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
            [textViewVar invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
        }];
    }
```

Currently what happens when I select the relevant table view cell is that I see the log statement `inside add custom info`, but nothing happens - no editing begins, the label does not disappear, and the text view does not become visible.

**How can I get the desired behavior of:**

1. user selects the table view
2. text view becomes visible and editable and covering label becomes invisible
3. text view is in editing mode, that is keyboard appears and user can type into text view

Here's what I've tried:

- verified log statements are running so methods are running
- verified that all IBOutlets are connected
- inserted a log statement in the table view cell method to check that it is printing a value correlated with that cell to confirm I am dealing with the correct cell.
- tried printing the text of a label, then changing it and printing. The log statement reflects the change, but again the appearance of the cell does not.
- modified the code (as now seen above) to save the last table view cell (the one I'm trying to change) as a class property of the table view controller so I know I have the same one. I see the same behavior - the cell's method to update its appearance appears to run (based on log statements), but I see no change. Even if I reload and setNeedsDisplay the table view, no dice.

My best guess would be that somehow the cell I am running the method on is not the cell I instantiated to display in the table view, but I am already using `dequeue` so what else can I do to troubleshoot or make sure I call the method on the proper cell?

Comment: How do you init the SignUpSurveyInputRowTableViewCell? Have you load it from nib already?

Comment: Since something like `self.surveyTextView.hidden = NO;` is so basic and yet still not having any effect, have you looked into if the IBOutlet is connected properly (if using SB)

Comment: @eagertolearn thanks for the suggestion, but I am sure the IBOutlets are connected, and for good measure I just redid the IBOutlets.

Comment: I don't think you should do a [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SignUpSurveyTableViewCell"] in the didSelectRowAtIndex method. Call tableView.cellForRowAtIndex instead.